# Getting paid by BitCoin on my website using Credit Card

Tags: buy-bitcoins, payment, website-integration, bitcoin-credit-card

Somehow, I think it's a trivial question yet I couldn't find an answer for it.

I have a website that gives online services. Like Image hosting etc'.

I want to receive money in BTC, but most people yet does not have BTC. So I thought, maybe they could pay using CreditCard, it will be converted to BTC and I will get it in BTC.

Is there a service that can do that for me ? Like a pay-pal on my website that people put in their CC details and I will be paid in BTC. I am aware that there will be a fee for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

cant think of a direct way.

merchant CC service
have them direct deposit to https://www.bitwage.com/

i doubt the connection will work since most merchant accounts will want to be able to pull funds from a bank in the event of a charge back.  but you merchant acct may decide to hold on to funds to make up for the loss.

might be better to get your customer to sign up for circle, coinbase/gdax, gemini, localbitcoins or one of the many other exchanges and have them send you bitcoin.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the ones [in this list](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_accept_Bitcoin,_for_small_businesses#Merchant_Services) may be what you're looking for.